# Creating Multiple Instances of Different Images in a GUI

Tags: java, image, user-interface, simulator

I need to create a Simulator with a GUI, and I need to use custom images to do that. I have spent more than 2 hours trying to figure out how to use multiple instances of multiple different images and add them all to a display, but I haven't managed to make it work yet. Below I am posting the classes as they have been modified by now, but I have tried many different implementation in the process. I know my code is probably messed up in the process, but even after starting over, I couldn't find a solution.

The concept is simple: I am gonna have a simulator about a liquer plant, and I need to simulate a particular configuration, visualized in the following image: (it is not the final visualization)

[image: liquer plant]

Up to now, I have just trying adding the silos (the big things :P). Below follows my LiqPlantSim class, which will eventually be the simulator GUI handler. Eventually, there will be another class where the buttons will be located, as a control panel for the simulator.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import javax.swing.*;

public class LiqPlantSim extends JFrame{

    public static Silo silo,silo2,silo3,silo4;

    public LiqPlantSim(){
        super("Liq Plant Simulator");
        this.setFont(new Font("Helvetica", Font.PLAIN, 14));
        this.setBackground(Color.red);

        silo = new Silo(160,0);
        this.add(silo);
        silo2 = new Silo(440,0);
        this.add(silo2);
        silo3 = new Silo(160,310);
        this.add(silo3);
        silo4 = new Silo(440,310);
        this.add(silo4);

        this.setSize(800,600);    
        this.setLocation(100,100);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.toFront();            
        this.setResizable(false);  
        this.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e){
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
    }


}
```

Here follows my Silo class.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.io.*;

import javax.imageio.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Silo extends Component{

    BufferedImage img;
    int x,y;
    public Silo(int x,int y) {
        this.x=x;
        this.y=y;
        try {
            img = ImageIO.read(new File("img/EmptySilo.png"));
        } 
        catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("ERROR");
        }
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.drawImage(img, x, y, null);
    }

    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        if (img == null) {
           return new Dimension(100,100);
        } 
        else {
           return new Dimension(img.getWidth(null), img.getHeight(null));
        } 
    }

}
```

Just for reference, here is my main function, where I try to create an instance of the LiqPlantSim, which will eventually be the simulator alone; there will be another window featuring the buttons to handle the simulator.

```
public class Simulator {

    public static void main(String [] args){

        LiqPlantSim sim = new LiqPlantSim();
    }
}
```

I am adding the Silo file for anyone needed.

[image: Silo]

Comment: Depending on the flexibility that you need, you could start with a basic/static image, on top of which you layer the more dynamic elements.  You will need to be able to map certain locations so you know where things go

Comment: The main problem is you're fighting the layout manager. When painting, the x/y position is relative to the components top/left corner, that is, 0x0 is the top left corner of the component it self. Focus on getting the Silo to work, allowing it to render other elements, then you can determine how to layout a group of silos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you're fighting the layout managers.  A component painting is performed from within the context of the component, that is, position `0x0` is the top left corner of the component.

Start by focusing on the individual requirements of the `Silo` class

```
public class Silo extends JComponent {

    BufferedImage img;

    public Silo() throws IOException {
        img = ImageIO.read(new File("img/EmptySilo.png"));
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, this);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        if (img == null) {
            return new Dimension(100, 100);
        } else {
            return new Dimension(img.getWidth(), img.getHeight());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getMinimumSize() {
        return getPreferredSize();
    }

}
```

This would also including anything else you might want to render on and how you might change the state, but I'll leave that to you...

Next, you need to decide how best to layout each component. My gut feeling is you are either going to need to use a `GridBagLayout` or maybe even come up with a custom layout manager which best meets your requirements

For this demonstration, I've simply used a `GridLayout`, but I think you will need something more complex and flexible for your overall needs

```
public class LiqPlantSim extends JFrame{

    public Silo silo,silo2,silo3,silo4;

    public LiqPlantSim(){
        super("Liq Plant Simulator");
        this.setFont(new Font("Helvetica", Font.PLAIN, 14));
        this.setBackground(Color.red);

        setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 2));

        silo = new Silo();
        this.add(silo);
        silo2 = new Silo();
        this.add(silo2);
        silo3 = new Silo();
        this.add(silo3);
        silo4 = new Silo();
        this.add(silo4);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setResizable(false);  
        this.pack();
        this.setLocation(100,100);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.toFront();            
    }


}
```

**Updated**

There are so many ways that you could layout the final view, all of which will come down to implementation specific details which are not available through your question.

I generally try and stick with pre-defined layouts, like `GridBagLayout`, wherever possible, it's mostly simpler that way, but sometimes, you might need to build your own layout manager to get exactly what you want.

At the end of the day, you want to do everything you can to separate and isolate the areas of responsibility, don't, for instance, be tempted to try and layout EVERYTHING in a single container, it will drive you nuts

The following uses a technique commonly known as compound layouts, utilising two different layout managers to accomplish the final goal.

[image: Layout]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.border.CompoundBorder;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new Brewery());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class Brewery extends JPanel {

        public Brewery() {
            setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            try {

                gbc.gridx = 0;
                gbc.gridy = 0;
                gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.SOUTH;
                JPanel top = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 2));
                top.setOpaque(false);
                top.add(new Silo());
                top.add(new Silo());
                add(top, gbc);

                gbc.gridy++;
                gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
                add(new Pipe(), gbc);

                gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH;
                gbc.gridy++;
                gbc.gridwidth = 1;
                JPanel bottom = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 2));
                bottom.setOpaque(false);
                bottom.add(new Silo());
                bottom.add(new Silo());
                add(bottom, gbc);
            } catch (IOException exp) {
                exp.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

    public class Silo extends JComponent {

        BufferedImage img;

        public Silo() throws IOException {
            setBorder(new EmptyBorder(0, 50, 0, 50));
            img = ImageIO.read(new File("img/EmptySilo.png"));
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            int x = (getWidth() - img.getWidth()) / 2;
            int y = (getHeight() - img.getHeight()) / 2;
            g.drawImage(img, x, y, this);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            Dimension dim = new Dimension(100, 100);
            if (img != null) {
                dim = new Dimension(img.getWidth(), img.getHeight());
            }
            Insets insets = getInsets();
            dim.width += insets.left + insets.right;
            dim.height += insets.top + insets.bottom;
            return dim;
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getMinimumSize() {
            return getPreferredSize();
        }

    }


    public class Pipe extends JComponent {

        BufferedImage img;

        public Pipe() throws IOException {
            img = ImageIO.read(new File("img/Pipe.png"));
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            int x = (getWidth() - img.getWidth()) / 2;
            int y = (getHeight() - img.getHeight()) / 2;
            g.drawImage(img, x, y, this);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            if (img == null) {
                return new Dimension(100, 100);
            } else {
                return new Dimension(img.getWidth(), img.getHeight());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getMinimumSize() {
            return getPreferredSize();
        }

    }
}
```

See [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) for more details

Comment: Ok... that allowed me to add the 4 silos. But still, I don't know how to make a full image looking like the upper one. Plus, how can i create my own layout manager?

Comment: @SiGm4 There's no real way I could possible give you a full answer, as many of the questions that need to be answered aren't available.  The updated example uses a combination of `GridLayout` and `GridBagLayout` (and some `EmptyBorder`s) to accomplish the basic look of your diagram, but may not be suitable because of details I don't know...maybe I should be doing your job ;)

Comment: Is there anywhere I can post the full assignment and get at least some advice/headlines as to what I should do? Or can I do that right here in Stack Overflow?

Comment: Kind of not really, it's not really what stack overflow is for.  What we're here for is for people who have a particular problem, which they've tried to solve, but are having trouble with. Try and see which points are giving you trouble and ask questions about those, providing some idea of how you attempted to solve it...